# Akka : Map Future of HttpResponse to create new HttpRequests

Tags: json, scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

My objective is to create a final Map[id, Result]. Here `Result` is case class like this below :

`case class Result(id: String, descr: String)`

Problem : I want to hit an API that returns a JSON. I'm going to parse this JSON and retrieve all the `member_id` fields from whole JSON.
`memberList : List[String]`

(Below is the part I'm blocked at, how to do this in Akka Streams and Http)
After this, I want to do for each string in memberList list:

- 1) Hit an API appending member_id to uri.
- 2) Parse the JSON to get    List of id and descr
- 3) Return tuple `List[(id, Result)]`

Finally, Flatten all lists to get final `Map[id, Result]`

How can I implement following two methods correctly `getResult` and `getResponse` (I have commented my code with rough idea about what I'm trying to do)?

Below is my Code :

```
case class Result(id: String, descr: String)

//// This is the Starting point of my CODE:
private def addFeatureByTag(tag: String) : Map[String, Result] = {

 val uri = "URI to get the Memebers"
 val result = Source
   .single(Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = uri)) 
   .map(getMembers) 
   .map(getResult)

}



private def getMembers(response : Future[HttpResponse]): 
Future[Source[String, NotUsed]] = {

response.flatMap {
  res =>
    res.status match {
      case StatusCodes.OK =>
        Unmarshal(res.entity).to[String] map {
          jsonOut => getAllMembers(jsonOut).  //// This method return the stream of `Members` (Strings)
        }
    }
  }
}

// How can I implement following two methods correctly `getResult` and `getResponse`
private def getResult(member: Future[Source[String, NotUsed]]) : Future[Source[Future[HttpResponse], NotUsed]] = {
 // member.map(mem => getResponse(PREFIX + mem)) 

}

private def getResponse(uri: Source[String, NotUsed]) = {

 // val resp = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri))

 // resp
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to use streams here? It looks like it'd be sufficient and simpler to use 'raw' futures:

```
val root: Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = uri)
val members: Future[List[String]] = root.map(getMembers)
val results: Future[List[(id, Future[Result])]] = members.map(ids.map(id => (id, getResult(id))))
val x: Future[List[Future[(id, Result)]]] = results.map(pairs.map { case (id, result) => result.map(r => (id, r))})
val y: Future[List[(id, Result)]]] = x.flatMap(Future.sequence)

def getMembers(response: HttpResponse): List[String] = ???
def getResult(id: String): Future[Result] = ???
```

Now this is of course rather roundabout/verbose, but I wanted to show the 'structure' of each step - once you understand what's going on you can simplify it a lot.